# How do I store the span tag next to the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi below I have a javascript code where what should happen is that it it appends a textbox and the [Open Grid] (which is in a span) next to the textbox. The textbox is stored in an array +"[]" so I tried putting the span after the textbox using .after() but the problem is that even though it displays the textbox, it does not display the span [Open Grid]. How can I get the hyperlink to be displayed next to the textbox?

Below is the code:

```
    <script>

    $(document).on('click','.showGrid', function(e) {

        $(".gridBtns").removeClass("gridBtnsOn");

        var value = $(this)
            .siblings('input[name=gridValues]').val();

        $("#btn" + value.replace(/\s/g, '')).addClass("gridBtnsOn");

        $('.optionTypeTbl').fadeToggle('slow');
        $(this).parent().append($('.optionTypeTbl'));
        $('.optionTypeTbl').css({

            left: $(this).position().left,
            top: $(this).position().top + 20

        });

        e.stopPropagation();

    });


        function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var context = $('#optionAndAnswer');

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $options = $("<td class='option'></td>");

        $('.gridTxt', context).each( function() {

var $this = $(this);
var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />")
    .attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
    .attr('value',$this.val())
    .appendTo( $options )
    .after("<span href='#' class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");

    $questionType = $this.val();


        });

        $tr.append($options);    
        $tbody.append($tr); 

        }

    </script>


    <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >


    <table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr class="option">
    <td>Option Type:</td>
    <td>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
        <span href="#" class="showGrid" id="showGridId">[Open Grid]</span>
    </div>
    <table class="optionTypeTbl">
    <tr>

        <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($num as $key => $val){
            if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
            echo"<input type=\"button\" value=\"$val\" id=\"btn".$val."\" name=\"btn".$val."Name\" class=\"gridBtns gridBtnsOff\">";        
            if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
        ?>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input class="gridBtns" name="btnTrueorFalseName"  id="btnTrueorFalse"  type="button"  value="True or False"  />
            <input class="gridBtns" name="btnYesorNoName"  id="btnYesorNo"  type="button"  value="Yes or No"  />
            </td>
            </tr> 
            </table>

            </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


    </form>
```

Comment: can you please show the code that converts $('.showGrid') into a link? it should be in your script.

Comment: You're missing important chunks of code in your example. Most importantly, I see nothing that looks like a link.

Comment: Well it is actually not a link, it is a span which I have made to look like a link using css which I posted above.

Comment: there also should be a chunk of js code that reacts on clicking on $('.showGrid').click() - can you please provide this?

Comment: can you please put the whole js code. i know you have it ;)

Comment: I have posted whole jscode and form code

Comment: ok, but there are no controls to react on click() when you clicking on  `$('.showGrid')`? where is this part of the code?

Comment: I have posted the click function on top of javascript code. The fsct is though Elen is that if there is no +"[]", then the Open Grid works fine, but as you know we need the +"[]" but this causes the [Open Grid} to not open anything up. The answer below does display the [Open Grid] but it doesn't open anything up when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because your:

```
var value = $(this)
            .siblings('input[name=gridValues]').val();
```

is actually:

```
var value = $(this)
            .siblings('input[name=gridValues[]]').val();
```

try this. if not. then there is `.map()` - which i haven't used before, but we can look into together...

---

UPDATE

may be you even need:

```
var value = $(this)
            .siblings('input[name=gridValues\\[\\]]').val();
```

Comment: Hi, I will test this and get back to you. I was just doing something else on my app so sorry for lateness.

Comment: You wonderful genius, you have solved it again. It was [] that was needed at the end. Thank You for your help again Elen :) Ur the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this = $(this);
var $optionsText = $("<input type='text' class='gridTxtRow maxRow' readonly='readonly' />")
    .attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
    .attr('value',$this.val())
    .appendTo( $options )
    .after("<span class='showGrid'>[Open Grid]</span>");
```

try this

Comment: I have done this and it does display the <span> [Open Grid] but the problem is that if you look at my updated code (but imagine your answer replaces the part of the code in the question), then every time I append the textbox and span into a table row, the [Open Grid] in the table row does not open up anything when I click on it. But if I remove the +"[]", then it works. But I need the +"[]" as well as a working [Open Grid].